# What should I consider when doing unit tests?

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, phpunit, lumen

What should I consider when doing a unit test? What steps? What cases? How many tests per function? etc.

I would also appreciate information about your experiences. Also I'm working with laravel phpunit. I did an example and it worked:

```
public function test_for_clientUser() {
    $this->json('POST', 'clientUser', ['id'=>'232421'])->seeJsonStructure([[]]);
}
```

I send a request with an id and it returns an array. What more prodrice do you add to this test?

Comment: Tests are supposed to check your assumed result, not retrieve data. You assume, that the response will be a json structure or that the response will be a success. You don't check the specific of the response. You test **logic**, not data. More about Laravel testing can be found [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/testing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can separate your tests into several actions(List, Store, Show, Update, Delete, etc) for each controller.

For example you can test your input validation for some post form:

```
   public function testStoringCityAsOwnerWithNotExistingCountryId()
{
    $input = [
        'country_id' => 0,
        'translations' => [
            [
                'name' => 'Варна',
                'lang' => 'bg'
            ]
        ]
    ];

    $response = [
        'errors' => [
            'country_id' => [
                trans(
                    'validation.exists',
                    ['attribute' => 'country id']
                )
            ]
        ]
    ];

    $this->asOwner()
        ->post('/cities', $input, $this->headers)
        ->seeStatusCode(ResponseCode::PERMISSIONS_DENIED)
        ->dontSeeJson();
}
```

Also you can test your listing information, pagination and many many other cases 
that you can find like bug.
**Actually the hole conception is that for every bug you should write new test!**

Answer (score 0):

According to this example (from *Lumen Programming Guide*):
https://github.com/Apress/lumen-programming-guide/blob/master/tests/app/Http/Controllers/BooksControllerTest.php

You would test more or less this:

```
GET /index
    - status code is 200
    - returns a collection of (well-formed) records

GET /show
    - status code is 200
    - returns a valid (well-formed) resource 
    - should fail with a non existing id (404)
    - should not respond with 200 if id is not numeric. Maybe 404

POST /store
    - the resource stores in DB
    - returns code 201 CREATED
    - returns a valid json qith a resource id

PUT /update
    - status code is 204
    - the resource has not the new value in DB
    - the resource now has updated data in DB
    - modified date was updated
    - should fail with a non existing id (404)
    - should not respond with 204 if id is not numeric. Maybe 404

DELETE /destroy
    - returns 204
    - should fail with a non existing id (404)
    - should not respond with 204 if id is not numeric. Maybe 404
```

As you are modifying a DB (than should be a testing DB, like a SQLite instance running on memory) these are not unitests but maybe functional. I can't assure. Author calls them *acceptance* tests but they are not since they are white-box tests (manipulating DB directly).